# How to Rotate textview without canvas

Tags: android, textview

I want to show a textview in 180 degree.How can I show textview like this[image] I have tried this by extending textview.But I can not  set the length and height I dont know why.

```
public class MyTextView180 extends TextView {

private int angle = 180;

public MyTextView180(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth());
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop());
    canvas.rotate(angle, this.getWidth() / 2f, this.getHeight() / 2f);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

public void setAngle(int textAngle) {
    angle = textAngle;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

[TextView | Android developers link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

how about not extending TextView and using setRotation(float), setRotationX(float) (and y).
Also dont forget to set the pivot points if necessary.

Comment: I am using android 2.2.i can not use setRotation() i have tried that